# Linux 64 bit on Virtual Box with Windows 7 professional 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox

I have HP ProBook 450 G1 Laptop with Windows 7 Professional.
It has an Intel Core i7 CPU which is claimed to have Virtualization Technology.
But I can't find it in BIOS to enable.

Now I installed Oracle Virtual Box (VirtualBox-4.1.4-74291-Win) and created a VM with 64-bit Linux.
When I try to start it and get the following error:

> VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration has been enabled, but is not operational. Your 64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to boot.
>
> Please ensure that you have enabled VT-x/AMD-V properly in the BIOS of your host computer.

Does anyone have getting around way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

think the BIOS is still the way to go, try this:

On boot press `F10` to enter Bios.

Go to: `System configuration -> Device configurations`

find there `Virtualization technology` and choose `enabled`. Press 'Enter'  key to Save it.

Go to: `File - > Save Changes and Exit` and choose `Yes`.

found this [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/activating-vt-x-from-bios/td-p/260444)

Answer (score 0):

See: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html

See if you can find it in your bios here:

Advanced mode->Advanced tab->CPU Configuration-> Intel Virtualization Technology

VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit host operating systems, provided that the following conditions are met:

1. You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see Section 10.3, “Hardware vs. software virtualization”).
2. You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.
3. If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon explicit request.

On 64-bit hosts (which typically come with hardware virtualization support), 64-bit guest operating systems are always supported regardless of settings, so you can simply install a 64-bit operating system in the guest.

Warning
On any host, you should enable the I/O APIC for virtual machines that you intend to use in 64-bit mode. This is especially true for 64-bit Windows VMs. See Section 3.3.2, “"Advanced" tab”. In addition, for 64-bit Windows guests, you should make sure that the VM uses the Intel networking device, since there is no 64-bit driver support for the AMD PCNet card; see Section 6.1, “Virtual networking hardware”.